# Como ler os logs do navegador?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma página em html que deverá exibir os
todos logs do navegador (`console.log`). Para que quando houver
um erro de script eu possa acessar essa página e ver os logs do navegador.

Comment: Você quer manter o histórico de logs? O log fica no lado do cliente, provavelmente se você quer os logs, terá que envia-los para o servidor e salvar em uma base de dados, por exemplo.

Comment: Como faço para exibir esses logs numa página html simples via javascript?

Comment: Dá pra habilitar isso, [veja aqui](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Comment: Tenho um webapp mobile offline, as vezes acontecem alguns erros de scripts que não da pra visualizar, gostaria de visualizar esses erros para corrigir bugs

Comment: ué, mas o console do navegador não exibe os erros mesmo sendo offline?

Comment: Eu já precisei ver no navegador desktop o log do navegador do celular. Para isso usei a funcionalidade de debug remoto do Chrome. Saiba mais em http://tableless.com.br/debug-remoto-com-chrome-android/

Comment: Já usei esses recursos para debug enquanto estou desenvolvendo, mas as vezes acontece erros quando o aplicativo esta em produção, se o navegador for Desktop consigo ver sem problema, mas quando for mobile não dá. Por que ele não tem a função F12 como no desktop. Gostaria de bolar um meio de colocar o log em uma pagina via javascript. tipo algo como document.write() que escreve direto na pagina.

Comment: Não dá pra tratar as exceções dos blocos mais importantes (`try` e `catch`, por exemplo) e fazer um método em AJAX pra reportar os logs ao servidor?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode sobrescrever a função, mas tem que voltar a sobrescrever se a página for atualizada:

```
<script>
/* coloque aqui a funcionalidade que deseja */
console.log = function(arg){ alert(arg); };

console.log('ola');
</script>
```

Abcs!